# Overwrite cellpadding of a specific cell of a table

Tags: html, css

My table has a `cellpadding` value of `10px`. But on a specific `<td>` inside this table, I would like to overwrite this value to zero. The following CSS does not seem to do the job.

```
<style>
    td.myclassname  {
        cellpadding: 0px
    }
</style>
```

Comment: there is no `cellpadding` in CSS, instead use `padding`.

Comment: use `padding` instead `cellpadding` (it's doesn't exist `cellpadding` in `css`)... anyway, visually it will affect only left and right, top bottom (visually) still stay.

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui terrific. Please post this as the answer.

Comment: @Disasterkid: provide your full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `cellpadding` in CSS, instead use `padding`. And maybe you should add `!important` too.

```
<style>
    td.myclassname  {
        padding: 0px;
    }
</style>
```

**Side note :** as @nelek said in the comments *" visually it will affect only left and right, top bottom (visually) still stay"*

Comment: Visually will affect if there's more than one row of text in that cell... for e.g. : `<td class="myclass">Row #1<br>Row #2</td>` and so on... it can be visually affected and it would not be... depend of content of specific cell.

Comment: Thank you for this, [Helene's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53865380/6248542) proves what you said.

Answer (score 5):

this is a working example: https://codepen.io/Helene-Andre/pen/PXWmxm

```
<table cellpadding="10">
  <tr>
    <td>hey</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>hey</td>
  </tr>
</table>


table {
  background-color: red;
}

td {
  background-color: orange;
}

tr:first-child td {
  padding: 0;
}
```